# Angular catchError in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am posting data to the server with the following method

```
  post<T>(url: string, body: T, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.path(url), body, options)
      .pipe(catchError((e) => {
        console.log('catch error: ', e)
        return this.formatErrors(e)
      }));
  }
```

The server is returning a 400 error with details:

`{
  "errors":[
    "Current password does not match"
   ],
  "isSuccess":false,
  "timeStamp":"2020-02-11T13:01:06.975597-05:00",
  "result":null
}`

However, all I am seeing inside the `catchError` for the `e` variable is `Bad Request` without any of the details.

How do I get to these details?

Comment: If you remove the catchError and just allow the call to fail, what do you see in the console and network tab?

Comment: use JSON.parse() method, like JSON.parse(e).

Comment: the error object should have a message property and so on. You shouldn't need to parse it as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

console.log('catch error: ', e.error), e.error object will have the response from the server